# Remove all hover effects in Kendo Menu for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm currently trying to use the [Kendo Menu](http://www.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/menu) on a project I'm working on. But the package comes with a whole bunch of hover styling I'm not really interested in using. Does anyone know of a way to disable / get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully clear.I am not sure what styles you don't need. If you can have much clarity in your question I can help you better.

Hover styles can be overridden using the class "k-menu k-state-hover"

```
.k-menu k-state-hover
{
   //add styles
}
```

Comment: I mean that everytime I hover over some element created by the Kendo().Menu() function there is a built-in hover effect that comes from Kendo's CSS-files. I don't want any of those hover effects in my project, since I already have defined my own set of hover effects.